# Using MEF, how to export a view for an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, mef, datatemplate

`enter code here`Maybe the title is not so specific.

The situation which I'm having is. I've got an `ItemsControl` where I insert many `ViewModels`, and this `ItemsControl` should have to show the `View` through `DataTemplates`.

So, I write these in a `ResourceDictionary`:

[image]

And then, I add this `ResourceDictionary` to the `ApplicationResources`.

This is so redundant and tiredsome.

I'm using `MVVM` also, so I was thinking if could be a way to use MEF to discover the corresponding the `View` that should draw. I was investigating that creating a custom attribute tag could be a good idea to simplify these redundant code, maybe adding this tag in the view telling it that this `ViewModel` should draw for this View, but I get lost with MEF.

The plan is to remove the `ResourceDictionary`.

Can you lend me a little hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been working with MEF recently so I could give you some help. But you will need to guide me through your problem. As I Understood from your post, you want to load data templates to application resources (resource dictionary) using plugins - to say dynamic. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, by discovery. When I said create a custom attribute tag, I was reffering to a custom Export, but here I do not know where should I set this Export or how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[System.ComponentModel.Composition.InheritedExport(typeof(ProblemView))]
public abstract class ProblemView : UserControl // or whatever your Views inherit
{
   public abstract Type ViewModelType { get; }
}

[System.ComponentModel.Composition.InheritedExport(typeof(ProblemViewModel))]
public abstract class ProblemViewModel : BaseViewModel // or whatever your ViewModels inherit
{
}

// in your App class
{
   [ImportMany(typeof(ProblemView))]
   public ProblemView[] Views { get; set; }
   [ImportMany(typeof(ProblemViewModel))]
   public ProblemViewModel[] ViewModels { get; set; }

   void MarryViewViewModels()
   {// called during MEF composition
      foreach (ProblemView view in Views)
      {
         foreach(ProblemViewModel vm in ViewModels)
         {
            if(Equals(view.ViewModelType, vm.GetType())
            {// match -> inject the ViewModel
               view.DataContext = vm;
               break;
            }
         }      
      }
   }
}

// example of usage
public partial class SomeView : ProblemView
{
   public override Type ViewModelType { get { return typeof(SomeViewModel); } }
}
```

Comment: if you need to use `DataTemplate`s, then what you could do is instead of `view.DataContext = vm;` do: `Application.Resources.Add(new DataTemplate { DataType = vm.GetType(), VisualTree = view })`

Answer (score 2):

In my host WPF application, I added this Import:

```
[ImportMany("ApplicationResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public IEnumerable<ResourceDictionary> Views { get; set; }
```

code behind for the ResourceDictionary:

```
[Export("ApplicationResources", typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
public partial class ItemView : ResourceDictionary 
{
    public ItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

For reference, the Xaml for the example ResourceDictionary looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
```

in  WPF application, before the main window:

```
// Add the imported resource dictionaries
// to the application resources
foreach (ResourceDictionary r in Views)
{
    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: Well, the idea is to eliminate the ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you how to setup something like this. You can look for further information in official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Best implementation would be using interface and duck typing.

```
public interface IModule {
    DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
    string Name{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Then for each plugin, inherit this interface

```
[Export(typeof(IModule ))]
public class SampleModule : IModule {
    private DataTemplate template;
    public DataTemplate IModule.Template {
        get { return this.teplate; }
        set { this.template = value; }
    }

    private string name = "SamplePlugin";
    public string  IModule.Name{
        get { return this.name ; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Class SampleModule is in separate assembly while IModule is in common with both Application and every module assembly.

Now you need to load every module available to application. This code snippet is from window of application

```
...
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<IModule> ModulesAvailable {get;set;}
...
public void LoadModules(string path) {
    DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
    catalog.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

Now you can just use foreach loop and add them to Application Resource

```
foreach(IModule module in ModulesAvailable) {
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(module.Template, module.Name);
}
```

This is just concept and code is not tested.

I ssed MEF in my [high-school final project](https://github.com/AleksandarDev/Project---Metro-Tables) I did few months ago, so you could take a look at my code. It is spreadsheet application with formula support where all operations and operands are loaded as plugins so it is very flexible.

Comment: You could add UserControl and IsDrawable to IModule and check for those properties when loading to determine what to do with each plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, give me please some minutes to get out of my job and test it.